# Python datetime returning wrong day of the week

Tags: python, datetime

Anyone want to venture a guess why the following code returns 4 when the actual day was a Monday (0)? Is it too far back for `datetime.datetime()`

`datetime.datetime(1678,12,16).weekday()`

[image: Per this screenshot, the day was a Monday]

Comment: *Where in the world* do you believe that day was a Monday?  That's far enough in the past that you have to take into account when each country switched from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: the reliable range of the `datetime` module is back to the year 1900. the behavior is undefined for dates before 1900. Maybe the `dateutil` library would do that better.

Comment: So when did Python adopt the change? I am curious why the American calendar and Python are not in sync. If the answer is that anything before 1900 is a free-for-all that's totally fine. I did find that for dates after 1800, the calendar _is_ aligned.

Comment: Python's datetime module uses the Gregorian calendar which was first introduced in 1582 in some countries but wasn't adopted in England and its colonies (which includes what is now the USA) until 1752. That is why your output is incorrect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_(New_Style)_Act_1750

Comment: You may be able to use the ```jdcal``` module for your use case. https://pypi.org/project/jdcal/